# Check and confirm

Tags: php, mysql

is it possible to make it 1st check if `$id` from ekstri_subcat exist/set in DB products and then confirm if not exist just delete? any tips on how to make it?

View

atm confirm is running on button click

```
<button type="button" 
data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ button_delete }}" class="btn btn-danger" 
onclick="confirm('{{ text_confirm }}') ? $('#form-filter').submit() : false;">
</button>
```

Controller

```
if (isset($this->request->post['selected']) && $this->validateDelete()) {
        foreach ($this->request->post['selected'] as $id) {
            $this->model_catalog_ekstri->delete($id);
        }
```

Model

```
public function delete($id) {

    $this->db->query("DELETE FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "ekstri_subcat` WHERE id = '" . (int)$id . "'");

}
```

Comment: So if the id is in the database, you want to confirm its deletion - and if not, you want to delete _what is not there in the first place_ without confirmation? Doesn’t seem to make sense. (Or what exactly do you mean by _“if not exist just run”_ …?)

Comment: Have you checked the affected rows? Not clear what you are asking at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. you can do it like:

```
if (isset($this->request->post['selected']) && $this->validateDelete()) {
    foreach ($this->request->post['selected'] as $id) {
        if(!empty($id)){
            $this->model_catalog_ekstri->delete($id);
        }
    }
}
```

You can check if it is in database, just selecting data with id and if it is not empty then delete. But it is not necessary for deletion. if there is not data with `id` it will not do anything and will not throw error.